# C++ - basic Qt question

Tags: c++, qt, contextmenu

Do I have any simple way to have context menu items, that aren't highlighted when mouse goes over them *(using Qt)*?

I want to make simple context menu with various item groups such as

```
|  Group1
|  -----
|  DoSomething
|  DoSomethingWow
|  DoSomethingCool
|  
|  Group2
|  ------
|  DoSomethingCoolHuh
```

and I want `Group1` and `Group2` act as simple labels so that users couldn't even focus them.

***Is this possible?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple solution which comes to my mind "out of the box" is to:
set those items disabled:

```
item.setEnable(False)
```

Then you could use some style to make it look different.
Hope this helps.